# Skip assigning if found duplicates

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a procedure that assigns values and sends it back. I need to implement a change that it would skip the assigning process whenever it finds duplicate iban code. It would be in this `FOR EACH`. Some kind of `IF` or something else. Basically, when it finds an iban code that was already used and assigned it would not assign it for the second or third time. I am new to OpenEdge Progress so it is really hard for me to understand correctly the syntax and write the code by myself yet. So if anyone could explain how I should implement this, give any pieces of advice or tips I would be very thankful.

```
FOR EACH viewpoint WHERE viewpoint.cif = cif.cif AND NOT viewpoint.close NO-LOCK:
    DEFINE VARIABLE cIban AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

    FIND FIRST paaa WHERE paaa.cif EQ cif.cif AND paaa.paaa = viewpoint.aaa AND NOT paaa.close NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.

    cIban = viewpoint.aaa.

    IF AVAILABLE paaa THEN DO:
        cIban = paaa.vaaa.

    CREATE tt_account_rights.
    ASSIGN
        tt_account_rights.iban = cIban.
END.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown the definition of tt_account_rights but assuming that "iban" is a uniquely indexed field in tt_account_rights you probably want something like:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cIban AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH viewpoint WHERE viewpoint.cif = cif.cif AND NOT viewpoint.close NO-LOCK:

    FIND FIRST paaa WHERE paaa.cif EQ cif.cif AND paaa.paaa = viewpoint.aaa AND NOT paaa.close NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.

    cIban = viewpoint.aaa.

    IF AVAILABLE paaa THEN DO:
        cIban = paaa.vaaa.

    find tt_account_rights where tt_account_rights.iban = cIban no-error.
    if not available tt_account_rights then
      do:
        CREATE tt_account_rights.
        ASSIGN
            tt_account_rights.iban = cIban.
      end.

END.
```

Some bonus perspective:

1) Try to express elements of the WHERE clause as equality matches whenever possible.  This is the most significant contributor to query efficiency.  So instead of saying "NOT viewpoint.close" code it as "viewpoint.close = NO".

2) Do NOT automatically throw FIRST after every FIND.  You may have been exposed to some code where that is the "standard".  It is none the less bad coding.  If the FIND is unique it adds no value (it does NOT improve performance in that case).  If the FIND is not unique and you do as you have done above and assign a value from that record you are, effectively, making that FIRST record special.  Which is a violation of 3rd normal form (there is now a fact about the record which is not related to the key, the whole key and nothing but the key).  What if the 2nd record has a different iBan?  What if different WHERE clauses return different "1st" records?

There are cases where FIRST is appropriate.  The point is that it is not ALWAYS correct and it should not be added to every FIND statement without any thought about why you are putting it there and what the impact of that keyword really is.

3) It is clearer to put the NO-LOCK (or EXCLUSIVE-LOCK or SHARE-LOCK) immediately after the table name rather than towards the end of the statement.  The syntax works either way but from a readability perspective it is better to have the lock phrase right by the table.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to achieve! Didn't expect such a great and easy answer so quickly. Tried, tested, everything works fine, massive respect.